# Create Hashmap from complicated JSON data

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap

I'm receiving this complicated JSON data and need help converting it into a hashmap to store into couchbaselite document database. It would then be queried using Couchbase lite queries for other functionalities. Im receiving the JSON data using retrofit and have designed the model class to handle the data received from the API.

```
  {
      'project_id': 'PROJ10001',
      'project_name':'Sample Project',
      'forms': [
      {
        'form_name': 'main',
        'form_id': 'FORM001',
        'variables': [
        {
          'id':'VAR0001',
          'variable_name': 'firstname',
          'variable_label': 'First Name',
          'input_type': 'text',
          'hidden_text': '',
          'required': '1',
          'options': {},
          'default_value': 'n/a',
          'max_length': 50,
          'min_length': 2
          'pre_condition': '',
          'post_condition': '',
          'order_in_form': '1'
        },
        {
          'id':'VAR0002',
          'variable_name': 'age',
          'variable_label': 'What is your current age',
          'input_type': 'number',
          'hidden_text': '',
          'required': '1',
          'options': {},
          'default_value': '0',
          'max_length': 3,
          'min_length': 2
          'pre_condition': '',
          'post_condition': '',
          'order_in_form': '2'
        },
        {
          'id':'VAR0003',
          'variable_name': 'gender',
          'variable_label': 'Gender',
          'input_type': 'options',
          'hidden_text': '',
          'required': '1',
          'options': {
            'type':'list', 
            'multi':'0',
            items:[
              {'label':'Male','value:'m', skip:''},
              {'label':'Female','value':f', skip:''}
            ]
          },
          'default_value': '0',
          'max_length': 3,
          'min_length': 2
          'pre_condition': '',
          'post_condition': '',
          'order_in_form': '3'
         }]
      },
      {
        'form_name': 'male_form',
        'form_id': 'FORM002',
        'variables': [
        {
          'id':'VAR0004',
          'variable_name': 'beard',
          'variable_label': 'How many shirts do you have?',
          'input_type': 'number',
          'hidden_text': '',
          'required': '1',
          'options': {},
          'default_value': 'n/a',
          'max_length': 3,
          'min_length': 2
          'pre_condition': '',
          'post_condition': '',
          'order_in_form': '1'
        }]
      }]  
    }
```

Comment: what is the issue, that you are getting while trying to converting this?

Comment: I am doing it manually, and i want a quick way to do it, via loop or something else

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible solutions for this problem. First is to have recursive class structure, but you already have that with [`JSONObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html). Other one is this:

```
class Option {
    String label, value, skip;
}

class Variable {
    enum InputType {
        OPTIONS,
        NUMBER,
        TEXT
    }

    String id, name, label, hiddenText, defaultValue, preContidion, postCondition;
    int maxLength, minLength, orderInForm;
    boolean required;
    InputType inputType;
}

class OptionsVariable extends Variable {
    enum OptionsType {
        LIST    
    }

    OptionsType optionsType;
    boolean multi;
    ArrayList<Option> options;
}

class Form {
    String id, name;
    ArrayList<Variable> variables; // sort this by orderInForm
}

class Project {
    String id, name;
    ArrayList<Form> forms;
}
```

Hope this helps! By the way, if you convert integers to strings in JSON you are not safe from `NumberFormatException`.